# Find a parametric equation for the tangent line at $t=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the following parametric equation...

$$x = (t-1)^2$$
$$y = 2$$
$$z = 2t^3 - 3t^2$$

I need to find an equation for the tangent line at $t=2$, so I thought to find the tangent line I need to find the derivative of the above, so I did...

$$2ti - 2i + 6t^2 k - 6tk$$

... and in parametric form this is...

$$x = 2t - 2$$
$$y = 0$$
$$z = 6t^2 - 6t$$

...but I do not think this is the right way to do it. Plus I don't know what to do with the $t=2$, and the answer is much different from my approach so I am not sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You are almost done. The derivatives give the right direction for $t=2$: $(x'(2),y'(2),z'(2))$. It remains to impose that the line goes through the point along the curve attained for $t=2$, that is $(x(2),y(2),z(2))$. In fact the parametric equation of the tangent line for $t=2$ is
$$t\to (x'(2)(t-2)+x(2), y'(2)(t-2)+y(2),z'(2)(t-2)+z(2)).$$

Comment: Yes, this gave me the right answer, I don't really understand why we must add (t-2)

Comment: In this way for $t=2$ the line goes through the point of tangency along the $(x(2),y(2),z(2))$.